# Python Tuple loop value error

Tags: python, list, tuples

I get the following error in Python 2.7 "need more than 0 value to unpack" when I execute these lines:

```
for row, row2 in results, results2:
  row = list(row)
  row2 = list(row2)
  row2[7] += row[7]
```

The objective is to add the value0 in results with the value0 in results2, then the value1 in results with the value1 in results2, ... I use the "fetchall()" function of the psycopg2 module.

Someone could please help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but if you want to add the first elements from the first tuple with the first elements from the second tuple, you can easily do it like this.

```
>>> tup = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
>>> tup1 = [(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)]
>>> tup
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
>>> tup1
[(4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)]
>>> x1 = [x[0] for x in tup]
>>> x2 = [x[0] for x in tup1]
>>> x1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x2
[4, 5, 6]
>>> list(zip(x1,x2)) #if you want to create another tuple
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> x1.extend(x2) #if you want to make a list
>>> x1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The lenght of the tuples does not matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would use map and zip to do this work:

```
from operator import add

list1 = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
list2 = [(7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]
list3 = [map(add, row1, row2) for row1 row2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```